# SOSL , in all fields and in any fields

Tags: sosl

I'm confused on when do i really need to use IN ANY FIELDS and in ALL Fields . Can someone clear things out for me thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding IN ALL FIELDS, that's the default, so if you don't have an IN, it's assumed to be IN ALL FIELDS - which means you wouldn't have to specify it.  This to me indicates you would only really explicitly include it in your SOSL if you wanted to have more clarity in your code (eg. if someone not fully familiar with SOSL reads your code, or if you go back to it after a while - there's no question as to what fields it's searching). Documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax.htm).

As for IN ANY, I'm not seeing reference to that in the documentation, and search results are turning up nothing, so I don't think that's valid SOSL - if you saw it somewhere, drop a link, I'd be interested to see.

Comment: sorry but I saw the IN any in a dump for my PD1 Certification. if its not valid then maybe there isnt really any IN any in SOSL. Thats why maybe there isnt anything cause I cant search it as well.

Comment: @Tachzxc Yeah, there doesn't appear to be.  Had a check of the SOQL documentation too and there's no IN ANY referenced there either.

Comment: Thanks Victor this is such a great help !

Comment: @Tachzxc You should never use exam dumps, for this reason (they're wrong) and because they are unethical. Please report all exam dumps to Trailhead support.

Comment: @DavidReed Thank you for mentioning who to report to - I found a thread of spam on the developer forums with contact info for receiving copies of dumps and I didn't know who best to report to.

Comment: Sure thing - here's the link to open a Case specifically for credential protection, including dumps: https://certification.secure.force.com/CredentialProtection/